# Difference between my aggregate() output and tidyverse output

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyverse, mean

I am using a dataset of flights. I try to calculate the average arrival and departure delay for different airports (origin).
I tried it with the aggregate function:

```
average_delay <- aggregate(cbind(arr_delay,dep_delay) ~ origin, FUN = mean, data = flights)
print(average_delay, digits = 3)
```

After that I tried it also with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
average_delay_tidy = flights %>%
  group_by(origin) %>% 
  summarise(arr_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE),
            dep_delay = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 3) %>%
  print
```

However I got different outputs:

Aggregate:

```
|origin|arr_delay |dep_delay |
:------|:--------:|:--------:|
|EWR   | 9.56     | **15.0**     |
|JFK   | 5.85     | **12.0**     |
|LGA   | 6.11     | 10.3     |
```

Tidyverse:

```
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
|origin|arr_delay |dep_delay |
:------|:--------:|:--------:|
|EWR   | 9.56     | **15.1**     |
|JFK   | 5.85     | **12.1**     |
|LGA   | 6.11     | 10.3     |
```

De difference is small, however, I do not understand how it is possible?
Can someone explain to me why these outputs are different?
Is it due to the NA values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  difference is so small that it seemed to be related to rounding as `tibble` does some print formatting for display, but in `aggregate`, if there are NAs, specify the `na.action` argument which by default is `na.omit` i.e. it will remove the row completely if there is a single NA element in the row.  Change it to `NULL`

```
aggregate(cbind(arr_delay,dep_delay) ~ origin, FUN = mean, 
    na.rm = TRUE,  data = flights,
        na.action = NULL)
```

-output

```
 origin arr_delay dep_delay
1    EWR  9.107055  15.10795
2    JFK  5.551481  12.11216
3    LGA  5.783488  10.34688
```

---

To confirm if there are `NA` elements

```
 colSums(is.na(flights[c('arr_delay', 'dep_delay')]))
arr_delay dep_delay 
     9430      8255
```

Comment: I tried command, but I got everywhere NA as output. I think it is related to rounding too, however how can I fix that in my code? Or in what way can I write it in a short note for clarification?

Comment: @WouterP it is because you didn't add the `na.rm = TRUE` for the `mean`

Comment: @WouterP Please check the updated output and code